# Inserting Alternating Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add blank columns in between columns with information in them, but I'm confused as to why my code adds exponentially decreasing amounts of columns starting with the second column.

```
Dim iCol As Integer

For iCol = lastCol + 2 To 3 Step -1
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Columns(iCol).Insert
Next
```

What I start with:
[image]

What I end with after running my macro:
[image]

Comment: "Exponentially decreasing"?! What does this mean? Looks ok to me, though you should post all relevant code so we know what's going on.

Comment: What's the value of lastCol?

Comment: it's just the number of the last column (7)

Comment: I can't replicate the example in your pics. Anyway, have you tried Jeeped's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
Dim iCol As long, lCol as long

with ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")
    lcol = .cells(1, .columns.count).end(xltoleft).column

    For iCol = lcol to 3 Step -1
        .Columns(iCol).Insert
    Next
end with
```

There has to be something in row 1 for .end(xltoleft) to 'catch'.

Comment: Not sure if the OP's use of colour in the pics is significant, but if it is, the colour of the last column will not be duplicated.